# Counting the times a word in a row appears in subsequent rows in r

Tags: r, dataframe, counting

I’m attempting to develop a specific string count script. There’s one step I can’t seem to solve.  I have several files (tab-delimited tables), each file contains a data frame with over 1,000 strings each in a row.  I’m trying to count the number of times a particular string in a row appears in another row as part of that row’s string.  Here’s what I have so far.  This yields a list of each file name, the number of times a string appears in a row by itself or inside another string. I’m able to develop the concept, but right now I have to search string manually, which is impractical when dealing with thousands of strings of different lengths.  As you can see, the script iterates over each file in the folder.  The result should only generate a list of those strings that appear in other rows and the number of times it does per file.  Also, the files don’t necessarily have the same list of strings so each file should be checked separately.

Here’s a simple example of the data frame.
    north.txt

```
1.  abcd
2.  bdcd
3.  tabcdt
4.  bdcad
```

I've been able to get the script to check for each word, but I have to input the word manually.

```
 library(stringr)
 library(tidyverse)

 # Read all .txt files in folder.
 files <- list.files(path="/Data/Processed_data/docs_by_name",  pattern=".txt")
 ###Action on each file
 # Select the column with the  sequences-clones
 for (i in files){
   print(i)
   data <- read.table(file =paste0( "/Data/Processed_data/samples_by_name/", i), sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
 # Compare selected string with strings of other rows and count matches
 # Select file
    for (t in unique(data)){
       word <- deframe(data)
       number.word <- str_count(word, “abcd”)
       repeats <- sum(number.word)-1
       print(repeats)
     }
  }
```

Here’s an example of what I’m hoping to get.

```
north.txt
abcd
2
bdca
1       

south.txt
abcd…
```